# c# - PKCS - Exporting to readable format

Tags: c#, pkcs#7

I have to sign and encrypt a message using PKCS:

```
EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = ...
// Add recipients
envelopedCms.Encrypt(recip1);
//
msg = envelopedCms.Encode();
```

I need the results in the format:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
base64 encoded msg
-----END PKCS7-----
```

Do you know how to export in this format in c#/.net?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just Base64 encode `msg` and wrap it in the BEGIN/END text?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?  (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225897/api-secured-by-pkcs7-cryptographic-message?rq=1))

```
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
resultString = resultString.Replace("\n", "").Replace("-----BEGIN PKCS7-----", "").Replace("-----END PKCS7-----", "");
signedCms.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(resultString));
```

To encode a string to a base64 string in C# .NET you can do this:
(I've added this because your question is unclear but states "base64 encoded msg")

```
// Get the bytes.
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString);

return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```